# Buying new furniture during the 3 weeks

Tags: halacha, transactions, three-weeks, shehecheyanu

The custom is (for Ashkanazim) that a shecheyanu is not made during the three weeks. See Siman 223 Sif 3 where you see that for "celim chadashim" (new vessels) a shecheyanu is made; in practice, though, people don't make a shecheyanu on furniture nowadays. Then would it be a problem to buy new furniture for ones house? For example, a large seforim shelf or any other large piece of furniture for the house that one would probably have simcha (joy) from having.

Comment: Who doesn't make a shehechiyanu on new furniture? Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 3):

For Ashkenazim, it seems that an individual cannot buy furniture during the Three Weeks but a couple or a family can:

http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5761/matos.html

http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5765/matos.html

Sefardim disagree and do not allow it:

http://dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=947